# Cannot get Rails REST API to work with Ember.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

I'm busy following [this](http://ember.vicramon.com/showing-a-lead) Ember.js tutorial, but I'm trying to implement it using the Ember 2.0 way of doing things (modules, using Ember CLI and the `ember-cli-rails` gem). It's rather difficult since none of the Ember guides follow these conventions.

As per the tutorial, I'm using Rails as a JSON API and it looks like everything works like it should in terms of serving the proper JSON responses. Problem is, I can't get my `leads` model to work.

I'm getting a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'typeKey' of undefined` error from `ember.debug.js`. I'm also getting a `undefined is not a function` error from `ember.adapter.js`

My project looks as follows:

**app/store.js**

```
  import DS from 'ember-data';

  export default DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
    url: 'https://localhost:3000',
    namespace: 'api/1'
  });
```

**app/router.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('leads', { path: '/' });
});

export default Router;
```

**app/adapters/application.js**

```
import DS from "ember-data";

var ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://localhost:3000',
    namespace: 'api/v1'
});

export default ApplicationAdapter;
```

**app/models/lead.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  firstName: DS.attr('string'),
  lastName: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  phone: DS.attr('string'),
  status: DS.attr('string', { defaultValue: 'new' }),
  notes: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

**app/routes/leads.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() { return this.store.find('lead') }
});
```

I don't see any HTTP requests being made to Rails, so I assume that it breaks even before trying to use the API. Can anybody please point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you seeing anything in your browser console?

Comment: Yup - third paragraph from top lists the two errors I'm getting in the Chrome console.

Comment: As far as I can see there is nothing wrong with this code. Can you recreate the problem in a fiddle? BTW why are you reopening RESTAdapter? This is dangerous.

Comment: According to that tutorial, this is how you configure Ember Data in store.js - by using reopen. Is there another way? I've added the whole project to a Git repo here: https://github.com/constantm/ember-crm/tree/master/frontend. I have no idea how to get this to work with a Fiddle. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the issue was store.js, which shouldn't be used here. Not sure why, but removing it causes everything to work as it should.

UPDATE: So, upon learning more of how Ember works, I now know the issue was not the file, but that Rails returns the wrong type of json back. The Ember REST adapter expects json keys to use an underscore, eg. `first_name`, while Rails returns it in camel case, eg. `firstName`.

To use Ember with Rails, you need to use the ActiveModel adapter. The newest version of ActiveModelSerialisers(AMS) supports JSON API.